# LINQ conditional and

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of arrays with filters that needs to matched as an "and" operation. I a filter array is empty it should be interpreeted as include everything for this filter:

```
List<string> cars = new List<string>();
List<string> flights = new List<string>();
            flights.Add("Boing");
            flights.Add("Airbus");

            var transports = new List<Transport>();
            var t1 = new Transport("Ford", "Boing");
            var t2 = new Transport("BMW", "Boing");
            var t3 = new Transport("BMW", "Flights INC");

            transports.Add(t1);
            transports.Add(t2);
            transports.Add(t3);

            //returns 0 result. In this scenario I would expect to get all with boing and Airbus and cars excluded from search because its empty
            var result = transports.Where(p => 
                (cars.Count>0 && cars.Contains(p.CarType)) && 
                (flights.Count > 0 && flights.Contains(p.FlightType))).ToList();


        cars = new List<string>();
            flights = new List<string>();
            cars.Add("BMW");
            flights.Add("Boing");

            IEnumerable<Transport> result2 = transports;

            if (cars?.Any() == true)
            {
                result2 = transports.Where(p => cars.Contains(p.CarType));
            }
            if (flights?.Any() == true)
            {
                result2 = transports.Where(p => flights.Contains(p.FlightType));
            }

            // all rows returned here I only want t2
            var r = result2.ToList();
```

Rahul guided be in the right direction. The arrays cannot be null. Solved it as:

```
                     statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p=> 
            (query.ClustersSelected.Count == 0 || query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)) && 
            (query.ParkNamesSelected.Count == 0 || query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName)));
```

Comment: this and condition means you have p.{property name } have some value ? right

Comment: If the array contains no values then Contains will be false. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Somethink like this but just working                                                                                                     statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p=> 
                (query.ClustersSelected != null && query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)) && 
                (query.ParkNamesSelected != null && query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName)));

Comment: @ThomasSegato - On the updated code, you should do `result2 = result2.Where()`, not `result2 = transports.Where()`. Then it will work. This is what I have in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use compound condition like below considering `ClustersSelected` is array type

```
.Where(p => query.ClustersSelected.Length > 0 &&  query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)
```

Comment: I tried that but get: Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

Comment: statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p=> 
                (query.ClustersSelected != null && query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)) && 
                (query.ParkNamesSelected != null && query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName)));

Comment: @ThomasSegato, array having null (not instantiated) and array with no elements are different

Comment: Ok will test with empty array

Comment: See last sample in intial post. In comments you see the problem.

Comment: Your were right. It cant be null. Fixed it as shown in inital post.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `if` would do it:

```
if(query.ClustersSelected?.Any() == true)
{
    statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p => query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster));
}
if(query.ParkNamesSelected?.Any() == true)
{
    statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p => query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName));
}
```

Each consideration adds another filter to the collection. I often use such code with the Entity Framework (and `IQueryable`) to generate smaller SQL queries, but it works just as well for LINQ to objects (IEnumerable).
I'm using `ClustersSelected?.Any() == true` to catch both cases of a `null` property, and an empty collection.

Comment: But isent the problem here that if both arrays has values, then the second statement will only be a sub set of the first statement? The code below dosent work, but it is what I am trying to do:    statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p=> 
                (query.ClustersSelected != null && query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)) && 
                (query.ParkNamesSelected != null && query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName)));

Comment: @ThomasSegato - If both arrays have values both conditions should be met. I think your code behaves the same.

Comment: Why not use the `Length` property of array instead using `Any()`?

Comment: I think the suggested code is an or statement where my code is and. I can try test, but I would be surprised :D

Comment: @Rahul - There are several reasons I prefer `Any` - It works with `IQueryable`, it is more expressive, and it doesn't assume an array (could be `Count` for other types). I also don't like writing `>0` multiple times - it is a tiny code duplication.

Comment: @ThomasSegato - My code behaves like an `and`: if both arrays have values, `statusViewResult` will be filtered **twice**. The variable `statusViewResult` points to something else after each `if`.

Comment: I tried testing it and it makes an or and not an and. See the inital post I have pasted the sample.